# How to pass data between views using viewFlipper

Tags: android, listview, android-viewflipper

I have three listViews in a viewFlipper and I want when user clicks on an item in the first listView, second listView to be displayed with related data from clicked item.

Is there any way to pass data between views using viewFlipper?

Comment: Can you add your whole Gradle file?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the official doc http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife. it says:

> ```
> compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.0'
> annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.0'
> ```